# react native app, Access child component and set state based on it

Tags: react-native

I have a main component called Dashboard which loads another component called Activity, and activity loads on the page just fine. here is activity:

```
export default class Activity extends Component{

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    FlatListActivityItems: [],
    activity:'',
    isWeightModalVisible:false,
    currentDate: new Date(),
    markedDate: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
};

db.transaction(tx => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM activityStatus', [], (tx, results) => {
    var temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
      temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
    }
    this.setState({
      FlatListActivityItems: temp,
    });
  });
});
```

}

```
render() { ....

}
```

That loads and does what I need it to within the component. I need to, however, access the FlatListActivityItems array to set the state of something in dashboard.

In my Dashboard component I load it like so:

```
export default class Dashboard extends Component{

  state = {
    activity:'',
  };
    render() {
    return(

    <Activity navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    )
    }
}

All I want to do in this case is take the first item in the FlatListActivityItems array with value activity (FlatListActivityItems[0].activity) and set it to the state for activity in dashboard so that I can access the state 'activity' in my dashboard class that loads the activity class.

How can I do that?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a funtion to Activity as a prop, in your db query call the function to set activity in Dashboard.

```
export default class Dashboard extends Component{

  state = {
   activity:'',
  };

  setActivity = (activity) => { 
    this.setState({ activity })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Activity 
        setActivity={this.setActivity} 
        navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    )
  }
}
```

Set activity where you set the initial data from the db.

```
db.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM activityStatus', [], (tx, results) => {

    var temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
      temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
    }
    // set activity in Dashboard
    this.props.setActivity(temp[0].activity);

    this.setState({
      FlatListActivityItems: temp,
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the role of the `Activity` component is to display the activity items, then you could use the `Dashboard` component as the logic component that holds the state.

Then, to display the activities, you can pass that list to the `Activity` component as a prop.

```
<Activity navigation={this.props.navigation} entries={this.state.activity}/>
```

And your `Activity` component will then use that list from `this.props.entries` instead of loading it on its own.